# Wicket RadioGroup, AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior, Form Submit?

Tags: wicket-1.5

I got a RadioGroup in Wicket with an AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior added.

Upon triggering the change, the behavior is sending a POST, but other changes on the parent form are  not sumbitted.

My question is: What is the correct way to achieve a complete submit?
(I need the complete form submit because there's other stuff going on with the form)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a standard wicket way to do this.
Would "pressing" an AjaxSubmitButton using JavaScript work for you?

Maybe someting like this?

```
onchange="$('button.mysubmit').click();"
```

(assuming that you have an AjaxSubmitButton with the CSS class `mysubmit`)

Comment: We ended up with adding a AjaxFormSubmitBehavior which is overriding onSubmit() and doing some magic in there on our own formcomponents